# Como obtener el nombre de un atributo con Jquery? Ejemplo data-id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un código donde tengo varios div con un "data-id" de distintos productos y necesito extraer el dato del numero, que está en el atributo data id, es decir el **1482**.
Ejemplo de unos de los div:

```
<div class="box-producto" data-id="1482">
```

Estoy intentado hacerlo con Jquery de la siguiente manera

```
 $(this).data("data-id") // retorna undefined
```

o también si trato con windows load , sin embargo me retorna init [window] y ningun dato manipulable.

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(this).data("data-id")
})// retorna init [window]
```

Comment: Hola, para extraer el valor, solo le pones el nombre no el data, asi: `$(this).data("id")`

Answer (score 2):

En JavaScript, [se nos recomienda](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) usar:

- La propiedad [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), la cual nos permite acceder a los valores de atributos personalizados que inician con `data-`
- Una vez que accedes puedes imprimir el valor deseado, en este caso sería el `id` el cual es el valor que se encuentra posterior al guión

Con una sintaxis como esta:

```html
    <div class="box-producto" data-id="1482">
      
    <script>
      let elemento = document.querySelector('.box-producto');
      
      console.log(elemento.dataset.id);  
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias, si quisiera por ejemplo obtener de todos los div que tengan "box producto" bastaría con querySelectorAll?

Comment: @EleWayne es decir todos los que tengan una determinada clase?, de ser así estás en lo correcto pero deberás iterar el node list que querySelectorAll te retorna

Comment: @Ele Wayne para que utilizar querySelectorAll si estás utilizando JQuery ?? Basta con acceder a tus elementos de la siguiente manera: $('.box-producto') esto accedera a todos los elementos que tengan la clase box-producto como dice BetaM con querySelectorAll tendrás que iterar lo que te te devuelva, pero si ya estás usando JQuery pues sácale provecho.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo solo con **`id`** dentro de la función **`data`** así:

```js
$(".box-producto").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-producto" data-id="1482">Prueba</div>
```